# Will I be interviewed by Immigration Officer even when I travel Domestic in their country?

Tags: air-travel, philippines, domestic-travel

Will I be interviewed by Immigration Officer when I travel Domestic in their country?

For example I will be going to the Philippines from Korea and will be staying in Manila for a couple of days. Then will go to one of their provinces via air like Cebu. I have a round trip ticket but I was thinking that I may not be using the exit ticket for some reasons and might stay for few more weeks (not sure when). So I was planning to book one way ticket going back to my country once I am decided with what exact date.

Comment: Which country? Can you give an example of an itinerary you're thinking of? "Domestic" _means_ **within** one country, not **to** a country from elsewhere.

Comment: I was able go get to kuala lumpur malaysia for dew days and of course went to immigration check. After few days had my flight going to other state in malaysia and didn't went through immigration check at all. Just went straight to departure gate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are different in every country and every airport, but in general, you will not go through an immigration check when flying domestically **within** a single country. You will generally go through an immigration check when flying internationally **in to** a country, with some exceptions, namely when flying between countries that are part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) in Europe (e.g. a flight from France to Germany is treated as a "domestic" flight even though they are two different countries, but a flight from the United States to France is still an international flight, and you will be interviewed by an immigration officer).

Note however that territories, exclaves, islands, etc... may be considered part of a country, but still separate from the immigration and/or customs territory of that country. Travel to/from these areas may be subject to special immigration rules and you may be subject to an immigration interview. The exact details depend on the territory and country concerned and should be the subject of a separate specific question.

However, you may be required to show ID at some point in the process, and in some cases there may be specific immigration checks, either a permanent set of systematic checks or through random controls. Passengers may be pulled aside for further checks at this point, and those staying within the country illegally could be caught. The risk of this depends greatly on the country involved and your circumstances.

Comment: I have a roundtrip ticket but I was thinking that I may not be using the exit ticket for some reasons and might stay for few more weeks (not sure when). So I was planning to book one way ticket going back to my country once I am decided with what exact date.

Comment: That should work (the country doesn't care what airline tickets you use), but the important part is that you not overstay in the Philippines. You likely will be admitted for [30 days](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=KR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=PH&selDest=Mexico&selTrans=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+transit+point(s)+above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) (and you must have a return ticket when you arrive, the other half of your roundtrip is fine), and you must leave the country within those 30 days unless you get an extension.

Comment: Nevertheless, sometimes you go through passport controls even on domestic flights. I know of two such places: Ireland (as far as I understand, their domestic flights are so rare that they don't bother themselves by organizing a domestic arrival area in Dublin airport) and flights from Jeju island to mainland Korea (a more open visa regime in Jeju - suppose it must be the same in other places like this, such as Melilla or Hainan, but don't know).

Comment: Yeah there's a lot of strange things that come up with territories that have different immigration laws.

Comment: How about in Malaysia? If I will be in Kuala Lumpur for 4 days and will be going to Penang on the 4th day via air, do I still need to be interviewed by the IO.

Comment: @NaeYiShin, ah yes, by the way, in Malaysia this also exists. You pass through passport control if traveling from peninsular states to Sarawak and Sabah (Eastern states have a degree of autonomy in immigration matters). Flying KL to Penang there is no passport control.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Thanks! So eventhough I don't have a new return ticket going back to my country, flying from KL to Penang will not be an issue?, right?  By the way, I'm aware about the visa and no plans in overstaying.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy I have seen something like that in the Schengen area too, when, for some reason (where the plane was coming from? ground handling? no gate available?) a Schengen flight departs from the non-Schengen terminal.

Comment: Depends on the size of the airport too. i haven't seen any "Inmigration check" on a Barcelona - Zaventem flight, but there was one (and slow, even for schengen-zoners like me) on a Madrid - Belfast. ( on the belfast airport).  if they only have 1 terminal, pretty sure there'll be a check on arrival.

Comment: @CptEric, Belfast is in the UK, which is not part of Schengen zone, so no wonder you had to go through passport control. And you must have had exit passport control in Madrid, too.

Comment: just the normal check to enter the terminal, put ID on reader / hand it to policemen on box. as said, the experience was a lot lenghtier in belfast than in Heathrow or Luton, everyone went through the same "line", and everything was done by personnel ( by hand) , workers of the airport, to  check the passport, no ID,  in luton i just passed my country ID through a reader and was inside UK in... 4 seconds.

Comment: @CptEric, This is actually another question. Many countries have dedicated (often automated) passport control lanes for their own citizens (or legal equals of their own citizens). If you had flown to Belfast from outside the EU, you'd undergo the same procedure. If you had flown to Belfast from another place in the UK, you'd skip passport control altogether.